# Order by next highest number

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've a query that pivots the ranking of game players in several exercices. In case their scores are tied, I need to untie by its highest ranking in each exercise.

Ex:

```
     total_points pos1 pos2 pos3
#1   5            1    3    1
#2   7            3    1    3
#3   7            4    1T   2
```

In 2nd place would be the player that is currently  in 3rd, because he has a 1st place tied with the player in 2nd place, but he has a 2nd place as next higher, while the player that is in second, has a next higher of 3. (T means tied and should appear next to number when the player has tied with another)

So desired result is

```
  total_points pos1 pos2 pos3
#1   5            1    3    1
#2   7            4    1T   2
#3   7            3    1    3
```

I think that the ordering is ordering by pos1 and then ignoring the other positions?

The subsequent query I'm using is

```
 SELECT totals.*, scores.*, warriors.*, results.*, positions.* 
       FROM (SELECT results . * , SUM( points ) AS total_points 
           FROM final_results AS results 
           INNER JOIN contest_trainings AS wods ON wods.id = results.wod_id 
           WHERE wods.show_date < NOW( ) 
           GROUP BY contest_id) AS totals, 
       final_results AS scores 
       INNER JOIN (
           SELECT wod1.*, wod1.wod_position AS pos1, wod2.wod_position AS pos2, wod3.wod_position AS pos3 
           FROM final_results AS wod1 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN final_results AS wod2 
           ON wod1.contest_id = wod2.contest_id 
           AND wod2.wod_id > wod1.wod_id 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN final_results AS wod3 
           ON wod2.contest_id = wod3.contest_id 
           AND wod3.wod_id > wod2.wod_id 
           GROUP BY wod1.contest_id) as positions 
        ON positions.contest_id = scores.contest_id 
        INNER JOIN contest AS warriors ON scores.contest_id = warriors.id 
        INNER JOIN contest_results AS results ON scores.contest_id = results.contest_id 
        WHERE totals.contest_id = warriors.id AND results.validated = 1 
        AND warriors.battle = 1 
        AND warriors.category = 1 
        GROUP BY scores.contest_id 
        ORDER BY totals.total_points, 
        positions.pos1, CAST(positions.pos2 AS UNSIGNED), positions.pos3
```

Comment: Is the T in the source table, as I can't spot it being added in the SQL? If so you probably need to remove it otherwise MySQL will probably do a character comparison. Try casting it to an int (ie, `CAST(ifnull(positions.pos2,0) AS UNSIGNED)` ).

Comment: @Kickstart I had greatest in the end, which wasn't really what was intended. Edited to fit the desired result also. Casting the row to int didn't make any change to output unfortunately

Comment: Not sure you can do what you want to do. You appear to want to chose the sort order depending on the values either side (but the records either side will vary as the sort progresses). However I am a bit confused as you refer in your original examples to _1st place tied_ , but that seems to refer to column pos2. That column is only relevant to the ORDER BY if column pos1 is the same, and it isn't here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The concept is, the least points you get, the better. You get X points from the position you have in each exercise (1,2,3). If you come first in exercise 1 you get 1 point, if you come 3rd in exercise 2 you get 3 points and so on. The sum of your points will define your standings. However, if you tie with someone (same points as another player) I need to untie, and the criteria is, the player who had a better standing in each exercise comes first. If im tied in first place with 1 1 4 (6 points) with someone who has 2 1 3, I win because I've had become first in more ex

Comment: That suggests your example data isn't quite as you want. For the 2nd and 3rd rows both have the same total points. One has a pos1 of 4 and the other a pos1 of 3. The one with a pos1 of 3 should come before the one with a pos1 of 4, but is shown the other way round in your desired results.

Comment: Well, I see I'm getting some trouble to express myself, sorry. The desired result is correct. If the total points are equal between 2 players, we'll have to untie. So, lets check both players best position in single events - both tie in a first place, so lets go to the next best position of both - number #3 has a 2nd place while #2 has a 3rd place, so, #3 has a better kicker, so its needs to go to position #2. Do you understand now?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. Order by total points, and for those with equal total points you want to order by who has the most 1st places, and within that who has the most 2nd places, etc? I will have a think and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in up to 4th position, then I would use try the following sort:-

```
SELECT totals.*, scores.*, warriors.*, results.*, positions.* 
FROM 
(
    SELECT results . * , SUM( points ) AS total_points 
    FROM final_results AS results 
    INNER JOIN contest_trainings AS wods 
    ON wods.id = results.wod_id 
    WHERE wods.show_date < NOW( ) 
    GROUP BY contest_id
) AS totals, 
CROSS JOIN final_results AS scores 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT wod1.*, wod1.wod_position AS pos1, wod2.wod_position AS pos2, wod3.wod_position AS pos3 
    FROM final_results AS wod1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN final_results AS wod2 
    ON wod1.contest_id = wod2.contest_id 
    AND wod2.wod_id > wod1.wod_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN final_results AS wod3 
    ON wod2.contest_id = wod3.contest_id 
    AND wod3.wod_id > wod2.wod_id 
    GROUP BY wod1.contest_id
) as positions 
ON positions.contest_id = scores.contest_id 
INNER JOIN contest AS warriors ON scores.contest_id = warriors.id 
INNER JOIN contest_results AS results ON scores.contest_id = results.contest_id 
WHERE totals.contest_id = warriors.id AND results.validated = 1 
AND warriors.battle = 1 
AND warriors.category = 1 
GROUP BY scores.contest_id 
ORDER BY totals.total_points, 
        IF(positions.pos1 = 1, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos2 = 1, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos3 = 1, 1, 0),
        IF(positions.pos1 = 2, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos2 = 2, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos3 = 2, 1, 0),
        IF(positions.pos1 = 3, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos2 = 3, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos3 = 3, 1, 0),
        IF(positions.pos1 = 4, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos2 = 4, 1, 0) + IF(positions.pos3 = 4, 1, 0)
```

It might be possible to improve this but I would need to see more of you original tables.

Note that your query seems like it might have some indeterminate results. For example your first sub query does a *GROUP BY contest_id* but returns everything from the final_results table. Not sure all those columns are dependent on a single value of contest_id (but can't be certain as I do not know how final_results and contest_trainings are laid out).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, I can't control how many records will be in the db, so it limits a lot to go only for the 4th position. I'll try to reformulate the question asap so everyone has a better understanding. Thanks again

Comment: Is there a max value of the pos fields?